# Is there a solution to unexpected global variable in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I just found at the script tag id's in chrome are created are stored on the window object.

```
<script id="deploy" type="text/html">blah</script>
```

`window.deploy` = ➜

```
<script id="deploy" type="text/html">blah</script>
```

`Object.keys(window)` does not include "deploy"

[Not a new issue apparently](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=24955)

So my question

Is there anyone who has found a solution to this (prevent chrome from polluting my world) the only thing I have come up with
is the following:-

```
$('script[type="text/html"]').each ->
# stuff
delete window[@.getAttribute 'id']
```

My "solution" risks deleting a global variable when not in chrome.

However without my solution chrome can overwrite global variables if the script id clashes.

WHAT A MESS!

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I came up with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script id="deploy" type="text/html">blah</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('script[type="text/html"]').each(function (index, element) {
                var id = $(element).attr('id');

                console.log(element);
                console.log(window[id]);

                if (window[id] === element) {
                    window[id] = undefined;
                }

                console.log(window[id]);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

This checks to see if the global is the same as the node before it deletes it.

Note that this happens with each ID, not only `script` tags. And it shouldn't be polluting your global scope, as Yoshi said, but the above solution should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

> If you name an element in your HTML document using the `id` attribute, **and if the Window object does not already have a property by that name**, the Window object is given a nonenumerable property whose name is the value of the `id` attribute and whose value is the HTMLElement object that represents that document element.

*(emphasize by me)*

Source: [JavaScript: The Definitive Guide, 6th Edition](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)

Comment: +1 for you for the reference, but window.deploy is undefined in firefox

Comment: @JamesKyburz I saw that too. Tough in IE, Safari and Chrome it was (could not test Opera). But anyway, I would not worry too much about it. First, the chance of a needed global being overwritten is not given. Second, **don't use globals**. ;)

Comment: agreed! I use https://github.com/substack/node-browserify enabling commonjs. I found the problem when I am trying a quick and dirty global variable that is removed shortly after creation.... thx